# Upgrade to .NET Core 3.1 - Can't instantiate singleton PhysicalFileProvider in services

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, fileprovider

I have a .NET Core solution containing an API project that was targeting .NET Core 2.1, and I upgraded it to .NET Core 3.1.  I've realized that there is a number of breaking changes from doing that, which I have gone through and modified to be compatible (such as converting `UseMvc` to `UseRouting` and so).  But now I am stuck on one:

When I try to run the API project, I get this runtime error:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider Lifetime: Singleton
> ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider': No
> constructor for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider' can be
> instantiated using services from the service container and default
> values.)

In Startup.cs, ConfigureServices, there is:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider, PhysicalFileProvider>();
```

which of course is the issue.  But I'm not sure how do I convert this to be both compatible and have the API work the way it has been.

I did find [an article on file providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that states:

> The FileProviderSample sample app creates the provider in the
> Startup.ConfigureServices method using
> IHostEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider:
>
> `var physicalProvider = _env.ContentRootFileProvider;`

But it's not clear as to exactly where within ConfigureServices that is supposed to go... or if that replaces the `AddSingleton`... or how that's going to affect the API's behavior.  So I'm not sure what to do with this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the service manually. Just inject `IWebHostEnvironment` instead and grab the file provider from there when you need it. Or if you *really* need that service you can instead use a factory. `services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootFileProvider)`

Comment: How would DI create an instance of  `PhysicalFileProvider` without specifying a root directory?

Comment: You could create an instance by yourself specifying the root, then registering that instance into the services collection, like this: `services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider, PhysicalFileProvider>(new PhysicalFileProvider("path/to/your/root/"));`

Answer (score 0):

How would DI create an instance of `PhysicalFileProvider` without specifying a root directory?

You could create an instance by yourself specifying the root, then registering that instance into the services collection.

This works for me:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  // (...)
  IFileProvider fp = new PhysicalFileProvider("C:\\path\\to\\by\\root");
  // or, you could get the file provider from the environment:
  // IFileProvider fp = _env.ContentRootFileProvider;
  services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider, PhysicalFileProvider>(_ => fp);
  // (...)
}
```

Then, I just inject it into my DI managed class:

```
IFileProvider _fileProvider;

public FilesController(IFileProvider fp) {
  this._fileProvider = fp;
}
```

As an alternative, and If you don't mind changing the constructor parameters of your class, you could inject `IWebHostEnvironment` instead. Then you could have easy access to the file provider from environment.